# Can I subclass "standard" arraylist iterator?

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, subclass

I need to iterate all the elements of `ArrayList` except the last one. So I want to create such iterator. But I don't what to implement the whole iterator, I need to override only the `hasNext()` method, so I would like to subclass a "standard" iterator. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be odd to modify the iterator to perform this traversal. The obvious thing to do is to write the "algorithm" as you want it:

```
public static <T> void eachExceptLast(List<? extends T> list, Operation<T> op) {
     Iterator<T> iter = list.iterator();
     if (!iter.hasNext()) {
         return;
     }
     T item = iter.next();
     while (iter.hasNext()) {
         op.run(item);
         item = iter.next();
     }
}
```

(Or use an index assuming a `RandomAccess` list.)

However, there's a much better way of doing this. `list.subList(0, list.size()-1)` (for a non-empty list) will return a view of the original list less the last element. It doesn't do a copy, and you can even use `Iterator.remove`.

Answer (score 3):

I think the better way to do that rather than overriding the default iterator is to iterate the `ArrayList` on your own. An `ArrayList`has a couple of method defined that can help you accomplish the task: `get(int)` and `size()`.
Everything you have to do is to get the total number of elements in the `ArrayList`(with `size()`) and then loop through the elements accessing each element directly in each iteration using the `get()` method. Your code would look something like this:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < myList.size() - 1; i++){
       element = myList.get(i);
       //do something
    }
```

Now with this principle in mind, you may create your own class to iterate the `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that implements either the [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) or [`ListIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) interfaces and then override the [`hasNext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#hasNext%28%29) method .